# learn how to use C# facebook sdk

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

where can I learn how to use it?
I want for instance an example that accesses a persons photo album and returns it's images.
Is there such a sample or some code, or anything?

how did you learn how to use the SDK?
please help, I don't know where to start.

I've seen the getting started code and samples on codeplex but hey are very basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only real-world open source app I found built upon [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) - http://code.google.com/p/facebooksteamachievements/

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. This is the only one I found also. For me even some samples would be good, but those on codeplex are too basic

Comment: @Ryan Yes, I agree. There are many asking for better samples and I think the "team" is working hard on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ or here: http://developers.facebook.com (go through the graph API and authentication parts for the developers website)